# Highlight the selected menu in spring with struts

Tags: spring, struts2

Is there any way to highlight the current menu which have been clciked.I am using left-mnu.jsp  in which i have all the menu which i am including in each jsp pages.Now i use a variable clicked and update this variable to some value when i open main jsp pages.Then am checking this variable in left-menu.jsp to highlight the appropriate menu.I know this is not a good approach.Can any one suggest me a good one for highlighting menu.

Comment: There's hover links highlighted via CSS. The menu has items. When the item is selected then it has such a status (selected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with CSS only, setting the id of the home with a word related to the id of the selected menu item, like described [here](http://www.hicksdesign.co.uk/else/cssnav/index.html).

Or with Javascript, matching the URL of the current page with the URL of the menu items (if they're `href`), like described [here (approach #2)](http://www.apaddedcell.com/highlight-links-current-page-css)

Or do it with JSP tags, etc...

Comment: great.thanks @Andrea Ligios your answer is simply superb.Thank you.