# Navigation tab using jquery. how to set default class for active

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

hi al am created tab using jquery.everything is almost done without adding default set to the tab menu. i create a `.show` class to make view the first contents of tab menu. if i clicked the other button means `the  show class removed from the default first menu` of the current tab and `also other tabbed menu in my page`.

Here my working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkranthVivek/69z5B/8/) shows the clear problem of this case

and my markup is like

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabheader">
        <li class="active" > 
            <a href="#tab-1"><span>FAQs</span></a>
         </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tabed_contents show">
       adasdasd
    </div>
</div>       


<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabheader">
        <li class="active" > 
            <a href="#tab-2"><span>FAQs</span></a>
         </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tabed_contents show">
       adasdasd
    </div>
</div>
```

my jq

```
     $('.tabs > ul.tabheader > li > a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.tabed_contents').hide();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(href).show();
    $('.tabs > ul.tabheader > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.tabed_contents').removeClass('show');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
})
```

show class which is used for first navigation of every tab to set as default view(show) after click other menu it removed from the respective element.while executing the class `show` removes for other classes too. that fiddles shows the problem clear.

```
.show{
    display: block !important;
}
```

how do i prevent this problem(removing the deafult show class).

Comment: I don't understand, why do you even need a `show` class at all? How do you use it?

Comment: show class which is used for first navigation of every tab to set as default view(show) after click other menu it removed from the respective element.

Comment: Not sure if [this can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14067239/1654265), totally different approaches, maybe worth knowing...

Comment: @AndreaLigios Here the problem is using multiple tab menu's in same page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what's going on is when you interact with the first menu, the appearance from the second menu is changed.  What you're going to need to do is set up different functions for each instance where you want this tab-browser to function.

**CSS**

```
.show{} 
<!-- Remove styling from show.  It is just used strictly for jQuery selectors. -->
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs first">
  <ul class="tabheader">
    <li class="active" ><a href="#fragment-1"><span>FAQs</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Credit bundle</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Delivery & turnaround times</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-4"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="fragment-1" class="tabed_contents current">adasdasd</div>
  <div id="fragment-2" class="tabed_contents">adasdasd</div>
  <div id="fragment-3" class="tabed_contents">adasdasd</div>
  <div id="fragment-4" class="tabed_contents">adasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs second">
  <ul class="tabheader">
    <li class="active"><a href="#fragment-8"><span>Ask a question</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-9"><span>Live chat support</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="fragment-8" class="ask_ques tabed_contents show">
    <p>Let our support team answer your questions...</p>
    <form class="ask_frm">
        <div class="row">
            <label>Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name2">
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="emaild2">
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
            <label>Questions: </label>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn blue small">Send</button>    
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
    <div id="fragment-9" class="liv_c tabed_contents">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="live_chats"></span>
            <a href="">Chat with our customer support</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.tabs-first > ul.tabheader > li > a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.tabed_contents').hide();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(href).show();
    $('.tabs > ul.tabheader > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.tabed_contents').removeClass('show');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
})

$('.tabs-second > ul.tabheader > li > a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.tabed_contents').hide();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(href).show();
    $('.tabs > ul.tabheader > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.tabed_contents').removeClass('show');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
})
```

I'm sure there's a much prettier way to do this using sibling selectors, but this will work just the same.