# How to highlight an active element in the menu when clicked in Struts2 tiles?

Tags: css, jsp, struts2, tiles

I am using struts2 with tiles configuration. I have some links present in the side menu. So, when a new page is forwarded, the active element highlight has been removed. I am using tiles configuration as follows.

```
 <definition name="login-success" template="/mainTemplate.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>    
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome Page"/>   
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/menu.jsp"/>   
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/Appointments/01_Dummy.jsp"/>   
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/footer.jsp"/>   
    </definition>  

    <definition name="login-error" template="/mainTemplate.jsp">   
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Login Error"/>   
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/login-error.jsp"/>   
    </definition>  

     <definition name="appointment" extends="login-success">
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/Appointments/02_FirstScreen.jsp"/>      
   </definition>
```

My Menu looks like below:

[image: My Menu]

When I clicks the link1, it should forward a jsp in the body. Meanwhile the link1 has to be keep on highlighted until I clicks another links such as link2 or Module2.

**mainTemplate.jsp:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!--<title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>-->
<title>ISIS Patient Monitoring Solution</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
    href="../images/isis_logo.jpg" />
</head>
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#header {
    padding: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 58px;
}

#sideMenu {
    padding: 6px;
    padding-bottom: px; /* Height of the footer element */
    height: 1 px;
}

* /
        #content {
    padding: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; /* Height of the footer element */
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div align="left" id="header">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        </div>
        <div id="sideMenu">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
        </div>
        <div align="center" id="content">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
        </div>
        <div align="center" id="footer">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My menu jsp looks as follows: In that I am using li tab and anchor tab for the link.

**Menu.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css" />
<title>ISIS Patient Monitoring System</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
    href="./images/isis_logo.jpg" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascripts/script.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul class="ui-state-focus">
            <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Module-1</span></a>
                <ul id="tab2">
                    <li><a href='appointment'><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Link 2</span></a></li>

                </ul></li>
            <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Module-2</span></a>
                <ul id="tab3">
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used `li:active, li:visited and li:focus`. There is no use. The highlight disappears when a new page loaded. Any help will be properly appreciated.

Comment: The highlighting works like radio button group, when one is pressed it's highlighted but others are unenlightened. In some cases you only need to check which button is active and update css.

Comment: So, u want me to change all li elements to radio button groups right?

Comment: If you are reloading a page, then the focus will be lost. You have to handle the recovering of the previous selection by yourself to highlight it. There are several ways to do this, I've listed some of them in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14067239/1654265)

Comment: When radio button is used it solves half of the problem (updating css) but the other problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you one mechanism tho highlight selection in menu.

**Step 1:** In css have a class of highlighting.

in css

```
// this is the only css which make selected menu appears different than other menu items
selected or highlighted 
{ 
 color: red;
 background: yellow;
}
```

This is your highlighted class.

**Step 2:** Add this class contents in such a way that `body` tag's id and the `ul` or `li` or `a` tag's is comes in combination.

in **css**

```
 body#link1 a#link1,
 body#link2 a#link2,
 body#link3 a#link3,
 body#link4 a#link4{
         color: red;
        background: yellow;
 }
```

**Note:** This class should be the last class in css, so no other css override this class

**Step 3:** In tiles pass a new parameter which will be id for different pages.

In **tiles.xml**

```
<definition name="appointment" extends="login-success">
  <put-attribute name="body"   value="/Appointments/02_FirstScreen.jsp"/>      
  <put-attribute name="menuselection"   value="link1"/>      
</definition>
```

**Step 4:** in menu.jsp use this tiles parameter

Look this below code, I added id in `body` tag and also in `a` tag

```
<body id="<tiles:insertAttribute name="menuselection" ignore="true" />">

<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul class="ui-state-focus">
        <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Module-1</span></a>
            <ul id="tab2">
                <li><a id="link1" href='appointment'><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a id="link2" href='#'><span>Link 2</span></a></li>

            </ul></li>
        <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Module-2</span></a>
            <ul id="tab3">
                <li><a id="link3" href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
                <li id="link4" class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

**Step 5:** Use the same id with menu's `li` or `a` tag whatever is suitable as per your css.

In **step 4** I already added id to `a` tag, you should also try with `span` tag if it does not work for you to get highlight.

```
 <a id="link1" href='appointment'><span>Link 1</span></a>
```

For different pages use different `menuselection` in tiles.xml.

```
<definition name="link2" extends="login-success">
   <put-attribute name="body"   value="/Appointments/somepage.jsp"/>      
   <put-attribute name="menuselection"   value="link2"/>      
</definition>
```

This will highlight link2.

**Now another case:** If you are not reloading your page, then you need to make a `jquery` function that changes the id of body tag.

in your js file

```
function enablelink2highlight(){
    $("body").attr("id","link2");
}
```

call this function on click event of your link, simple.

```
<a id="link2" href='#' onClick="enablelink2highlight();"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
```

**Note:** Make sure you do not have multiple `body` tag, but if you have multiple body tag you can give class to body tag and filter it in `jquery` selection.

I hope this mechanism may help you. Please share your result with me. so I can help you more.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I have fixed this problem by passing the sublink ID and main Link ID along with the jsp forward.